# Give IOS application that is paid for free

Tags: ios

I know that you can send out promo codes that allow users to get the application but these codes can stop working. I don't want to use any beta testing sites like TestFlight. Is there any way to give someone permeant access to the application if it is paid for free?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just make sure that the promo code is redeemed before it expires?!

Comment: Give them a promo code and make sure they use it within 4 weeks. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You might want to change to a free app with in-app purchases for the paid content. If you do that:

You can add a custom URL scheme to the app. Then, you can add some code to the app to process the URL used to open the app, check the information that it provides and activate all of your paid features.

How you decide to do the 'check' of the information is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot upload your application directly to device (for this you will need to use provision profiles) - then no, either all can download it for free or everybody should pay/use promo codes.

Of course you can "buy" it once, or change price to free and then get back after user installed it, but I suppose it is not your variant